# Syntax error: unexpected end of file when logging in

Tags: lubuntu

I am new to Ubuntu and I have this problem when restarting my PC. I tried to find something on internet but I did not find something. Help me!!

Here is my .profile . I dont see a 29 line

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fd
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin"
```

Comment: You haven't provided your release details  (i'd guess Lubuntu/LXDE, but it's better if we aren't guessing and are told).

Comment: According to the error-popup, there are an error in your .profile in line 29, unexpected end of file. Probably you have edited the file and made an error. Please update your question with the content of `.profile` (as text, not a screenshot).

Comment: `if` should end with **`fi`** not **`fd`**

Comment: The second last line says `fd` it should probably be `fi` to end the `if ... then` statement starting a few lines above.